Http URL added in security filter chain but getting 401 Unauthorized in response but user data is saving in the database
I am trying to add some user in the database, I have implemented JWT in my project and I have added all the required dependencies. Problem which I am facing is when I try to register any new user I get 401 Unauthorized in response but data gets stored in the database. I have added "/register" in the filter chain and allowed permiteAll.
SecurityConfig.java class
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;


    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) ->
                requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler));
        http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
        http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

AuthTokenFilter.java class
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);
    @Autowired
    private  JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserService customUserService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String token = parseJwt(request);
            if(token!=null && jwtUtils.isValid(token)){
               String username=jwtUtils.getUserName(token);
               UserDetails userDetails=customUserService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication=
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            LOG.error(String.format("Error is filter chain : %s",ex.getMessage()));
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request){
        String jwt=jwtUtils.getJwtHeader(request);
        LOG.debug("AuthTokenFilter.java : token{} ",jwt);
        return jwt;
    }
}

UserController.java class
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImp.class);

    private final UserServiceImp userServiceImp;

    public UserController(UserServiceImp userServiceImp) {
        this.userServiceImp = userServiceImp;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody User user){
        LOGGER.info(String.format("User data is %s: {}",user));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userServiceImp.registerUser(user));
    }
    
}

AuthEntryPoint.java class
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOGGER.error("::::::ERROR::::::"+authException.getMessage());

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

        final Map<String,Object>mapper=new HashMap<>();
        mapper.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        mapper.put("error", "Unauthorized");
        mapper.put("message", authException.getMessage());
        mapper.put("path", request.getServletPath());

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), mapper);
    }
}


If your user was created, the 403 is not coming from the register endpoint.  Perhaps an error is occurring (maybe during serialization) that's redirecting you to /error, which is under guard.

Yes it is refirecting to /error. How to fix this ?

The first step is to determine the error that's occurring.  Post the log output so we can get an understanding of what is causing it.
